# python3 cannot load qrcode module

Tags: python, pip, qr-code

I have installed qrcode package as `pip install pyqrcode`

Then when I open a python2.x shell and import it there, no errors are given. But when I open a python3 shell and try to import it there it says

`ImportError: No module named 'qrcode'`

I import it as `import qrcode`

When I installed the package with `pip` it says `Downloading PyQRCode-1.2.tar.gz`, meaning that it is installing the last version. But in [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQRCode)
it says that it also support python3.

What's the correct way to import it?

Comment: From the [documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/PyQRCode/#usage), you should do `import pyqrcode`.

Comment: @dazedconfused it says again that `No module named 'pyqrcode'
`

Comment: Could you give the output of `pip freeze | grep pyqrcode`?

Comment: It does not show anything

Comment: Then I think you don't have `pyqrcode` installed successfully

Comment: Yeah you are right. I just figured it out now

Answer (score 3):

You need to download a separate package for python 3. `pip3 install pyqrcode`

Then you can access it. Of course you will need to install `pip3` first if you don't have it.

Comment: I installed with pip3 still getting the same error.